# How to go back in History with Android Device Backbutton in Phonegap 3.5.0?

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery-plugins, overriding, device, back-button

I am having some issues with the Android Device Backbutton.
I am trying to go back in History but everything fails.

`window.history.back()` (Fails)

`history.go(-1)`        (Fails)

`history.back(-1)`      (Fails)

I already implemented the backbutton override, i just want to go back in history.

Pls help me!

```
       <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Wait for device API libraries to load
    //
    function onLoad() {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    }

    // device APIs are available
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        // Register the event listener
        document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
    }

    // Handle the back button
    //
    function onBackKeyDown() {
        //Help me!
    }

    </script>


</head>
<body onload="onLoad()">
    <div data-role="page" id="mainPage" data-ajax="false" data-title="App24">
        <!-- Navi auf der linken Seite -->
        <div data-role="panel" id="navipanel" data-position="left" data-position-fixed="true" data-display="push">
            <div id="navi">
                <ul id="ulNavi"></ul>
                <ul id="ulNaviSub"></ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Header -->
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
            <a id="navibutton" href="#navipanel" data-role="link" data-icon="navi" data-theme="h"></a>
            <h1 id="maintitel"></h1>
            <a id="backbutton" onclick="back()" class="ui-icon-back" data-role="link" data-theme="h">&nbsp;</a>
            <a id="sharebutton" class="ui-icon-share" data-role="link" data-theme="h">&nbsp;</a>
        </div>
        <!-- Content-->
        <div data-role="content" id="content">
            <div class="scroller">
                <div id="naviContent" class="navigation"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using *window.history.back()* should work. Anyhow, if you're using jquery-mobile **you could use *data-rel="back"***  and let jquery-mobile do that work for you (you don't need any javascript function):

```
<a id="backbutton" data-rel="back" class="ui-icon-back" data-role="link" data-theme="h">&nbsp;</a>
```

Comment: hello :) and thank you for your answer but i want to go back with the device backbutton.

Comment: I'm sorry. In my mobile (Android) the device backbutton causes to go back in the history by default (no need to capture a keyPress); using Phonegap and jqm.